# SQL not accepting AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql, auto-increment

New programming learner here. I am trying to create a table for blood donors, and have the id be automatically incremented upon registering new donors, but sql gives an error around auto_increment as the screenshot shows.
[Screenshot of the error]

[image]

Comment: There is need to put a space in between `phone TEXTNOT`, just add a space `phone TEXT NOT`

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: Noted. Thanks, but the screenshot was not of the code, more so of the output received and the error. But like I said, duly noted.

Comment: Show us the code, the error message, and also add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot, I am assuming it is a SQLite database. SQLite uses the keyword "AUTOINCREMENT", not "AUTO_INCREMENT".

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, this, and skipping the "NOT NULL" did the trick.